# Flatten 2D Array Into Separate Indexed Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have the array:

```
 $total =array();

 Array ( 
    [0] =>  Array
            (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            ) 
    [1] => Array 
            (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7 
            [2] => 8
            ) 
    [2] => Array 
            ( 
            [0] => 9 
            [1] => 10 
            ) 
    )
```

I need to dynamically change each array into an indexed array for a Cartesian function.

Here is how I need the code to look for the function to work correctly:

```
$count = cartesian(
Array(1,3),
Array(6,7,8), 
Array(9,10)
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have tried flattening, looping, using array_values, using just the array itself and I keep falling short.

Thanks

Nick

```
function cartesian() {
$_ = func_get_args();
if(count($_) == 0)
    return array(array());
$a = array_shift($_);
$c = call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $_);
$r = array();
foreach($a as $v)
    foreach($c as $p)
        $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
return $r;
}
$count = call_user_func('cartesian', array($total));
print_r($count);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your arrays already look exactly the way you want them to. `array(1,3)` is the same as `array(0 => 1, 1 => 3)` and both are an array with the value `1` at key `0` and `3` at key `1`. Exactly what the debug output shows you.

It seems you just need to pass them as separate arguments to the function. E.g.:

```
cartesian($total[0], $total[1], $total[2])
```

For dynamic lengths of arrays, do:

```
call_user_func_array('cartesian', $total)
```

Comment: Nice mentioning the call_user_func_array !

Comment: @deceze Looks exactly what I need thanks! I have edited my question to show the code I am using, would you be able to show me how to implement the call_user_func_array please? Thanks

Comment: @deceze I have been working on this all evening, I've read and re-read over the link you gave me. I am not returning any error or 'False'. It's just not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Nick

Comment: Why `call_user_func('cartesian', array($total))`?! Isn't it supposed to be `call_user_func('cartesian', $total)`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your `$total` array is `multi-dimensional` array with `numeric indexed`. So yo can try like this

```
$count = cartesian($total[0], $total[1], $total[2]);
```